# Getting a 400 Bad Request when Angular HttpClient posts a Set<> to a SpringBoot endpoint

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, post

I am exposing an endpoint that accepts a Set<> as a @RequestBody this way :

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Response> addTeamOwner(@RequestParam("teamName") String teamName, @RequestBody Set<String> emails, HttpServletRequest request){...}
```

And my Angular frontend is calling this endpoint like this :

```
let params = new HttpParams().set('teamName', teamName);
let url = `${UrlManager.TEAMS}/addOwners?${params.toString()}`;
this.httpClient.post<any>(url, emails);
```

For some reason I'm getting 400 Bad Request : `HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: 'Bad Request', url: 'http://localhost:4200/api/teams/addOwners?teamName=DEMO_TEAM', ok: false, …}`

It seems that the `Set` that Angular is sending is not accepted by the backend because when I change to an Array everything works fine !

FYI, my API is SpringBoot and my frontend is Angular.

Comment: Don't you have stacktrace from the server? It's somewhat hard to guess like that.

Comment: There is no logs on my backend but when I open Chrome DevTools I can see that the payload is empty {}

Comment: If the payload is empty, that's the problem. `@RequestBody` requires a payload to map to whatever object you need, otherwise returns 400, unless you specifically mark it as required = false. The problem lies somewhere in the frontend, incorrect serialization, not sending at all, something else, i can't really say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is not possible to serialize data sent within `Set` because the data are not stored as properties.

The solution was to convert the set to an array this way :

```
this.httpClient.post<any>(url, [...emails]);
```

and the backend is able to deserialize it as a `Set` correctly.